# Validate command not perfoming its task in an entry inside of frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I don't understand why this code is not perfoming the validate command.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="red")
canvas.grid()

frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor="nw")
txt = ["1", "2"]

def get_data():
    print("AAAA")
    return False

for i in range(2):
    t = tk.StringVar()
    t.set(txt[i])    
    e = tk.Entry(frame, validate="focusin", textvariable = t, state="readonly", validatecommand=get_data)
    e.grid(row=i)

root.mainloop()
```

There appears to be two problems:

1. Validate command acts once where the entries are declared (it shouldn't act at all), and I can deal with that typing lambda: get_data
2. The entries don't respond to the "focusin" after that.

I am writing a large project and made this sample to be as simple as possible.

Thank you all!

Comment: it works for me when I don't use `textvariable=`.

Comment: I works for me with `textvariable=` when I remove `state="readonly"`.

Comment: Why are you using validation on a readonly widget? That makes no sense.

Comment: As I said, I made a sample to simplify the problem, the thing is that there is a table made with entries, so once it detects that an entry has been ·"clicked" it triggers another functions.. so I need to know which entry has been focused. That is the point. Thanks"

Comment: _"so once it detects that an entry has been ·"clicked" it triggers another functions"_ - the right way to do that is with a binding, not with validation. Validation should only be used for validating input. If you need to know which entry has focus, there are commands to answer that question for you (`focus_get`).

Answer (score 0):

From the canonical [tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm#M7):

> In general, the textVariable and validateCommand can be dangerous to mix... The danger comes when you try set the textVariable to something that the validateCommand would not accept, **which causes validate to become none** (the invalidCommand will not be triggered). The same happens when an error occurs evaluating the validateCommand.

Since your validation command always returns `False`, the validation command gets set to `None` because the value of the textvariable is considered to be invalid.

Comment: It is solved, I changed the return statement to True instead of False from the validatecommand.